# Core Data takes too much time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have around 200,000 four letter words, which i want to use in my app. I don't want to use it as a CSV file in my app. So i using core data now. Now i am loading all these values to core data at the starting of the app only for the first time. And i am retrieving these values after sometime.

So this procedure too much time, more than 20 seconds i think. I just want to access a single word, also i just want to know whether a word already exists in the core data or not, is there any other ways to do this, except looping through the whole array.

Simply, I want to check whether a word exists in core data or not, also i want to access a word by ints index, I don't wanna loop through all the objects. Is there any other way .? I want to do this in a fraction of a second.How am i supposed to load 0.2 million words .? Reading from CSV takes more than 2 minutes, in my app. Any suggestion for importing array of string into core data.?

This is the code i am using in my project.

```
 // Save it into CoreData


    func saveName()
    {

        //1 Getting AppDelegate

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //2 Fetching Entity Description by corresponding entityName

        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Content", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        let tempManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        //3 Setting Values for managedObject


        for input in self.fourLetterWords
        {
            tempManagedObject.setValue(input, forKey: self.kMainAttributeName)
        }

        //4

        var error: NSError?

        if !managedContext.save(&error)
        {
            println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Showing Values From Core Data

    func showOutput()
    {
        var myArray : Array<String> = []

        //1
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Content")

        //3
        var error: NSError?

        let fetchedResults =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
            error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

        if let results = fetchedResults
        {
            for inputObject in results
            {
                if let value : String = inputObject.valueForKeyPath(self.kMainAttributeName) as? String
                {
                    myArray.append(value)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's a lakh, Alvin? And for your task you should take an array, not a database.

Comment: @gnasher729: not an array, a set. Alvin: also familiarize yourself with predicates if you use core data.

Comment: 1Lakh means 0.1Million.

Comment: @vikingosegundo How am i supposed to load 0.2 million words .? Reading from CSV takes more than 2 minutes, in my app. Any suggestion for importing array of string into core data.?

Comment: I agree, loading the words into a set will allow much faster matching. You don't even really need a CSV - simply a file with one word per line would do.  Show the code you are using to load a text file that is taking two minutes - It shouldn't take that long to read less than a megabyte

Comment: loading 200,000 words should not take 2 min. you have some error.

Comment: When you run Instruments, where does it tell you the processing cost lies?

Answer (score 0):

The most important method you need to skip looping is this:-

```
1 .filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
```

**To search use this:-**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF CONTAINS %@", search];
```

Just go through this Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html), it will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Reading from CSV takes more than 2 minutes, in my app.

This doesn't sound right. I constructed a file with 200,000 4-letter words. Reading it into memory, separating by comma takes in average 0.51 seconds on my iPhone 6.

The file:

```
xgnu,dkiw,reff,iebs,qhdh,eqeb,osxr,stac,qiaa,fliq,pmhs,zllt,…
```

I repeated this task 10 times

```
var array = Array<Double>()
for i in 0..<10{
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("words", ofType: "csv")
    var text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!


    let start = NSDate()
    self.allWords = text.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    let stop = NSDate()
    let duration = stop.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
    array.append(duration)
}

let total = array.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})
let maxDuration = array.reduce(-Double.infinity, combine: { max($0, $1) })
let minDuration = array.reduce(Double.infinity, combine: { min($0, $1) })

let average = total / Double(array.count)


println("duration: \(total), average: \(average), min \(minDuration), max: \(maxDuration)")
```

result:

```
duration: 5.14537298679352, average: 0.514537298679352, min 0.495729029178619, max: 0.524932980537415
```